# How to use NOT inside Xpath for IMPORTXML function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The formula I currently use is:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/",
           "//select[@class='team-news-dropdown']
               /option
                 /@value[not(@value='/injuries/football/')]"
          )
```

The result of the current import is:

```
/injuries/football/
/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/
/injuries/football/austria-bundesliga/
/injuries/football/belgium-first-division-a/
/injuries/football/brazil-serie-a/
```

If it's exactly this value, I don't want it to appear in the result:

```
/injuries/football/
```

The expected result would be:

```
/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/
/injuries/football/austria-bundesliga/
/injuries/football/belgium-first-division-a/
/injuries/football/brazil-serie-a/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/",
 "//select[@class='team-news-dropdown']
  /option
  /@value[not(@value='/injuries/football/')]"), "offset 1", 0)
```

[image]

or:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/",
 "//select[@class='team-news-dropdown']
  /option
  /@value[not(@value='/injuries/football/')]"), 
 "where not Col1 = '/injuries/football/'", 0)
```

[image]